# Curve drawing, not Bezier

Tags: curves

As a kid I would draw curves like the red line below, hopefully it is reasonably clear how I have constructed that.
I understand that the green line is the quadratic Bezier curve, what is the red line called?

[Curves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/go9TO.png)

Comment: This should probably be on http://math.stackexchange.com/.  As it stands, it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 1):

The red curve in your picture is a parabola (which still can be represented as a quadratic Bezier curve). See this [link](http://mysite.du.edu/~jcalvert/math/parabola.htm) for more details.